# fix object overlapping upon itself

Tags: objects

I created an object that, in part loops over upon itself causing problems. I wish to have the object become unified at the join of the loop shaped part and the squared edge rectangle part.[image]

Comment: Hello, I don't think that there's any automatic tool to fix that, you need to correct the topology manually

Comment: a little more info would help.

Comment: maybe share this part of your object so that we can try to correct the topology? https://blend-exchange.com/ But the best would be to redo it from scratch

Comment: Ok, I'm dissecting the parts and deleting overlaps, then rejoining parts, merging vertices, basically manually altering it all.